# Computed column date from nvarchar field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `nvarchar(50)` field (DateHr) that holds the date and time in the following format: `yy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` (ex. `12/04/11 16:49:23` which should translate to `April 11, 2012 4:49 PM`).

I am having a hard time trying to manage the date values in this format.

I was wondering if I can create a column as a `DateTime` datatype and use this new field.

Comment: Why don't you use the proper data type in the `DateHr` column?

Comment: I can't change the way the value is entered and if I change to datetime datatype it will be interpreted as `12/4/2011 4:49:23 PM` which is incorrect.

Comment: Is it possible instead to create a trigger when a new record is created to update a new field with data type datetime and I use that instead?

Comment: Why do you need a trigger for this? You can add a new computed column without messing with a trigger.

Comment: Having a hard time trying to figure out to query a range of dates.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just have a view?

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.View_MyTable
AS
  SELECT 
    DateHr, 
    DateHr2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), CONVERT(DATETIME, '20' + DateHr), 100)),
    DateHrProper = CONVERT(DATETIME, '20' + DateHr)
  FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

Now your query can be:

```
SELECT DateHr2 FROM dbo.View_MyTable
  WHERE DateHrProper >= '20120412'
  AND DateHrProper < '20120413';
```

This way you don't have to mess with the schema of the table, and you can investigate the persisted computed column approach only if you need to. If you do add a computed column, I would add it as a datetime column, not as a different string representation of the same date. Do your "make it pretty" stuff on the output, not in the storage.

**EDIT** if you can control writes to the table via a stored procedure (highly recommended), and you don't let users run ad hoc inserts/updates, then you can change the base type and not have to worry about the nonsense that they might enter. For example:

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
    SET DateHr = CONVERT(DATETIME, '20' + DateHr);

-- assuming there are no rows left where `ISDATE(DateHr) = 0`, 
-- but you'll have to test that:

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN DateHr DATETIME;
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ProcThatUpdatesMyTable
  @key    INT,
  @DateHr NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF ISDATE('20' + @DateHr) = 0
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Please enter a valid date.', 11, 1);
    RETURN;
  END

  UPDATE dbo.MyTable 
    SET DateHr = CONVERT(DATETIME, '20' + @DateHr)
    WHERE key = @key;
END
GO
```

Now your query, where you want `April 11, 2012 4:49 PM` as the output - unfortunately there isn't a native way to easily translate to that format within SQL Server. You can do it with all kinds of string manipulation, e.g.:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT 
    d = DATENAME(MONTH, DateHr) + ' ' 
      + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DAY(DateHr)) + ', ' 
      + CONVERT(CHAR(5), YEAR(DateHr)), 
    t = CONVERT(CHAR(26), DateHr, 109)
  FROM dbo.blab
)
SELECT d = d + LEFT('0' + RIGHT(t, 13), 5) + ' ' + RIGHT(t, 2) FROM x;
```

This is very close to your desired output:

```
April 11, 2012 04:49 PM
```

You can do more string manipulation to remove the leading 0 on the hour if you want.

Much better to format this on the client. On the plus side, you can do this easily in SQL Server 2012 with the new `FORMAT()` function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DateHr, 'MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt')
  FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

Result:

```
April 11, 2012 4:49 PM
```

And of course I'll mention again that the ultimate solution is to not have your users enter freetext date format in the first place. I guarantee you someone will enter April 5 when they meant May 4 or December 2011 when they meant November 2012. Having them select from dropdowns or a calendar control, where you can have complete oversight over the strings that are passed to SQL Server in a safe format instead of relying on the person's mood that day, will ensure you always know the date is what the user selected (even if their regional format might not be what you expect).

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), cast('2012/04/11 16:49:23' as datetime), 100)
```

it is strange, but both casts are necessary

EDIT:

```
create table test_date
(
DateHr varchar(50),
DateHr2  AS (CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), cast('20'+ DateHr as datetime), 100))
) 

insert into test_date values ('12/04/11 16:49:23')

select * from test_date


12/04/11 16:49:23   Apr 11 2012  4:49PM
```

Comment: I created a view with the following `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CAST('20' + DateHr AS datetime), 100)` and output in the format I wanted correctly. I tried adding the convert line to the formula under Computed Column Specification, but get an error validating the formula message.

Comment: I ran the command `Alter Table dbo.myTable ADD DateHr1 AS CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CAST('20' + DateHr AS datetime))` successfully, but when go in the Management Studio and edit something in the table I get the error message "Error validating the formula for column". Also won't let me set to Is Persisted: "Computed column 'test1' in table 'Tmp_DR_Transaction' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.". The output is correct nevertheless.

Comment: After I created the new computed column, how do I query for a date?

Comment: Deigo, why isn't it datetime? Formatting belongs on the final query. I don't see the benefit of storing two different string representations of a date. Rick, you should not be "editing" this data in Management Studio. Use an UPDATE statement and update DateHr. You can't update DateHr2 because it's based on DateHr. If you could update it, then it could potentially not match DateHr, and what sense would that make? As for persistence, I don't know that it's necessary in this case, but you need a trick to persist datetime with certain formatting. Formatting belongs on the front end.

Comment: hi Aaron!
that was actually the way I found to show the data the way Rick wants. It is a string on the DB, so I cst to a date time to have a "date" format and then back to varchar to display the way he wants. I saw that you did pretty much the same on your solution..

Comment: Except I didn't store it. And I *also* had a datetime column so that a where clause makes sense.

Comment: what do you mean by didnt store. A computed column is not save to the DB unless is created as PERSISTED. Its always calculated on the fly. As your view

Comment: @Rick tried to persist it. And whether the data is actually stored is not really what I meant - I meant that the metadata has changed, there's a new column, etc. I fail to see the value of two different string representations of a datetime. Ideally you'd get rid of both and just store the correct type; if not, a computed datetime column makes a lot more sense to me than a computed string.

Answer (score 1):

One option is a computed column. For example,

```
declare @t table(s nvarchar(50), dt as convert(varchar(30),case isdate(s) when 1 then cast(s as datetime) end,121))
insert into @t(s) values ('12/04/11 16:49:23')
update @t set s='20'+s where ISDATE(s)=1 and LEN(s)<19 --prepend w/century
insert into @t(s) values ('john') --demonstrate bad date string handling here
select * from @t;
```

Result:

```
s                                                  dt
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
2012/04/11 16:49:23                                2012-04-11 16:49:23.000
john                                               NULL
```

EDIT: Add handling for bad date values

EDIT: Custom date 24h format - yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)

EDIT: Prepend the original date with century, as needed

Alternatively, you can prepend the century in the computed column:

```
declare @t table(s nvarchar(50), dt as convert(varchar(30),case isdate('20'+s) when 1 then cast('20'+s as datetime) end,121))
insert into @t(s) values ('12/04/11 16:49:23')
insert into @t(s) values ('john') --demonstrate bad date string handling here
select * from @t;
```

Result:

```
s                                                  dt
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
12/04/11 16:49:23                                  2012-04-11 16:49:23.000
john                                               NULL
```

Comment: In my example dt should of returned 2012-04-12 16:49:23.000

Comment: Solution updated to return yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h) format

Comment: The problem I have is that cast is converting the date incorrectly. `12/04/11 16:49:23` is converting to `2011-12-04 16:49:23` when it should be `2012-04-12 16:49:23`.

Comment: Prepending the original date w/century should do the trick, as demonstrated in my update above.

Comment: Ok added the following formula to the computed specefication `dt as convert(varchar(30),case isdate('20'+s) when 1 then cast('20'+s as datetime) end,121)`. I like it, but can I query a range of dates with this new field?

Comment: Yes, you can simply recast as `date`, like this: `select * from @t where cast(dt as date) between '1/1/2012' and '12/31/2012' -- query by date range`

Comment: Why do people insist on using regional formats for string literals? Only `YYYYMMDD` is safe here. Try the query in your latest comment with `SET LANGUAGE BRITISH;`. And if you think `YYYY-MM-DD` is safe here, try it again with `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;`...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - idk, I'm just answering the question as posed. If it were me I would either compute the original column as datetime2 in a new column, and then format as needed at the query level; or even just convert the original string at the query level, whichever performs better.

Comment: The WHERE clause you wrote is what I was talking about. `m/d/y` is not a very safe format to recommend for string literals in a where clause, no matter what the question is, IMHO...

Comment: Yes, that's why I would personally design the solution around datetime or datetime2. But I assume that the OP has some extenuating circumstance that requires a string literal.

Comment: I don't think you're quite following what I'm saying. There is no reason your where clause, which you suggested in a comment, has to use an unsafe and ambiguous m/d/y string literal. Forget for a moment about the underlying table or the OP's extenuating circumstances; your where clause is against an expression of type date, and as such would be much better with a safe format. If that's the way you want to write your code, that's fine, but I think the average reader deserves to know that it is not universally safe.